# Where is stored the xml file?

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin android project, I have added a xml file in the root of the project, and I configure it to copy to the folder deployment.

But when I try to load the file with this code:

```
XDocument miXdConfiguracion = XDocument.Load("configuracion.xml");
```

I get an error the file can't be found.

In the properties of the xml file I have set compile action to content and copy to output folder always.

What I would like to have it is a simple xml file with some configuration of the application, to can load, modify and save.

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: 1. copy your file into `Assets` folder, 2. set file's build action to `AndroidAsset`, now you can access to the file using `Assets.Open ("YOUR_FULL_FILE_NAME")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Build Action of the file to "android asset". AndroidAsset files can be accessed using Asset.Open("yourfilename"). That might help you.